# what is the way to do in mvc method for projects

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, mvvm

how to convert  in mvc?

this is the code done in mvvm .

model:-

```
class EventModel: NSObject {

    var name :String!
    var location:String!
    var imageurl :String!
    var date:String!
    var place:String!
    var id:String!
    init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let id = dictionary["id"] as? String,
            let location = dictionary["location"] as? String,
            let imageurl = dictionary["imageurl"] as? String,
            let date  = dictionary["date"] as? String,
            let place = dictionary["place"] as? String else {
                return
        }

        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.id = id
        self.imageurl = imageurl
        self.place = place
        self.date = date
    }





}
```

datasourcemodel:-

```
class EventDataSourceModel: NSObject {

    var dataListArray:Array<EventModel>? = []


    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()
        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil{

            newArray = self.getJsonDataStored2()
        }
        else{
            newArray = array!

        }

        var datalist:Array<EventModel> = []
        for dict in newArray{

            let model = EventModel(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
    }



}

typealias dummyDataSource2 =  EventDataSourceModel
extension dummyDataSource2{

    func getJsonDataStored2() ->Array<Dictionary<String,String>>{

        let jsonArray = [["id":"201","name":"Dosa Fest","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Shiraz Garden"],["id":"202","name":"Organic Vegan Fest","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"15 Jan 2018 30 Jan 2018","place":"Evergreen Organics"],["id":"203","name":"Food Of Life Time","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Turkey Central"],["id":"204","name":"Tea Time","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Doha Food Mall"],["id":"205","name":"Dosa Fest","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Shiraz Garden"],["id":"206","name":"Organic Vegan Fest","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"15 Jan 2018 30 Jan 2018","place":"Evergreen Organics"],["id":"207","name":"Food Of Life Time","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Turkey Central"],["id":"208","name":"Tea Time","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Doha Food Mall"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

        return jsonArray
    }

}
```

viewmodel:_

```
class EventViewModel: NSObject {



    var datasourceModel:EventDataSourceModel


    var id:String?


    var filteredListArray:Array<EventModel>? = []

    init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel: EventDataSourceModel) {
        datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
    }


    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> EventModel{
        return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]

    }

    func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {

        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }


}
```

viewcontroller:-

```
class EventViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource{


    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private var eventViewModel :EventViewModel!

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, withViewModel viewModel:EventViewModel) {

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        eventViewModel  = viewModel
    }



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.tableView .reloadData()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return eventViewModel.numberOfRowsInSection(section: section)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let identifier = "eventcell"
        var cell: EventCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? EventCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "EventCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? EventCell
        }

        cell.setEventData(events: eventViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

        return cell
    }


}
```

tableview cell:-

```
class EventCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var cellview: UIView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }


    func setEventData(events:QM_EventModel)
    {
        self.name.text = events.name

    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

How to do in mvc.?I am confused ,because  many sites related with mvc showing difference style.Aim is same but the method of writing code s difference.So this makes the beginer confusion.The above code is in mmvm.So what all changes needed to make in mvc.

Comment: how to solve the problem

Comment: @Md Rashed Pervez can anybody please solve the problem

Comment: For setting the architectural pattern (MVVM to MVC) you have to set it by urself. How the architectural pattern of MVC works? Please see these links - https://www.raywenderlich.com/132662/mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach   ,   https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-three-ways-to-pass-data-from-model-to-controller-b47cc72a4336